# Transformar System.out.println para ingresarlo en la parte grafica

Tags: java, java-swing

Buenas amigos programadores, tengo una situación: estoy transformando un programa que utiliza `System.out.println` para *imprimir* en pantalla y debo convertirlo en su consecuente parte grafica.

Parte del código que necesito transformar es:

```
public int getCart(int num) {
        PantallaJuego pj = new PantallaJuego();
        int getCart = 0;
        switch (num) {
            case 0: //Valor del arreglo

                System.out.println("1");//carta a imprimir
                getCart = 1; //Es el valor temporal para asignar para la suma 
                break;
            case 1: //Valor del arreglo
                System.out.println("2");//carta a imprimir
                getCart = 2; //Es el valor temporal para asignar para la suma 
                break;
            case 2:
                System.out.println("3");
                getCart = 3;
                break;
```

pero necesito tomar esas salidas e ingresarlas en un `JLabel`, ¿cómo podría transformarlo?

¡Agradezco las sugerencias!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes hacer reemplazar los `System.out.print("")` por `JOptionPane.show.MessageDialog(null,"")` y en general otros tipos de dialogos como de entrada de datos. O también podrias usar JFrame y crear una ventana personalizada  con JLabel, JTextField, y JButton.

Ejemplo de JOptionPane: [aqui](http://codejavu.blogspot.com/2013/12/ejemplo-joptionpane.html)

Comment: Buenas es parecido pero ocupo ponerlo en un JLabel para imprimir el resultado en una ventana o panel.